# menu at centre on adding width to nav ul otherwise at corner

Tags: html, css, user-interface, web

Following is a css the menu items appear from the corner of the bar
http://jsfiddle.net/bej85/

and I edited the css and added

```
width:19em;
```

in #nav ul section of css and the menu items came to center.

http://jsfiddle.net/bej85/1/

I am not very clear as why adding a margin brought menu items to center, 
I am new to css kind of thing and html so I want to understand this behavior.

Following is code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>Jenware | Personalized Gifts</title>
<style type="text/css">


/* styles for navigation */
#nav {
    background-color: #2322ff;
    height: 3em;


}
#nav ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding: 0;


} 
#nav ul li {
    font-weight: normal;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    float:left;     

}

 #nav ul li a {     
  display: block;   
  padding: .5em;    
  border: 1px solid #ba89a8; 
  border-radius: .5em;  
  margin: .25em; 

} 

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="nav">
<ul>
<li><a href="">House</a></li>
<li><a href="">Baby</a></li>
<li><a href="">More</a></li>
<li><a href="">About</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<!-- end #content -->
</body>
</html>
```

and here is how it appears  when width:19em is in nav ul section
[image: menu at centre]

and if width:19em is not present in nav ul section then it appears as below 
[image: menu at corner]
What  I want to know is why is this behavior of width:19em in nav section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not because of `width: 19em` but it is because of `margin:  0 auto` applied to the `UL` element.

`margin: 0 auto` brings any Block element to center if it has some width applied which is less than its parent element's width.

If you are not aware of the `UL` elements width then use `display: inline-block` to it and give `text-align: center` to its parent element.

Comment: thanks for informing that please if there is some link mentioning same give me I have wasted a lot of time for this

Comment: @RegisteredUser In docs, you can find only documentation but not explanation about a trick. and I am sure this is a trick(_a basic one_). anyway, here `margin: 0 auto` has syntax of `margin: top&bottom left&right`. So, the left and right extends to give a margin auto which brings the element in center. No need to worry, you will understand it slowly :)